# How to fix input string was not in a correct format in sql on C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

```
public static String AccountNumber;
public static double oldBalance, newBalance;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\CSharp\ATM\DB\LoginDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

private void iconButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        newBalance = oldBalance + Convert.ToInt32(txtAmmount.Text);
        try
        {  
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;              
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Account SET AccBalance ='" + Convert.ToDouble(newBalance) + "'WHERE AccountNum =" + txtAccount.Text.Trim() + "", connection);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(data);
            if (data.Rows.Count >0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Deposit Success", "Deposit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Deposit Faild", "Deposit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            }
            

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" " + ex, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}      

private void GetBalance()
{
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
            AccountNumber =Form1.AccountNumber;
            int accounts=Convert.ToInt32(AccountNumber);
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT AccBalance FROM Account WHERE AccountNum='" + accounts + "'", connection); 
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(data);
            oldBalance = Convert.ToInt32(data.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
}

private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetBalance();
}
```

When I load the Form, I get an error

> Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: In your sql query, remove single quote around account number if in your sql table if that column is of integer type.

Comment: Check the ``Convert.ToInt32(txtAmmount.Text)`` and ``Convert.ToInt32(data.Rows[0][0].ToString())`` maybe one of them is not convertable to ``Int32``

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: You have so many issues with your code: SQL injection as mentioned, you should use parameters. Dispose connection command and adapter with `using`, do *not* cache them. An `UPDATE` should not be in a `SelectCommand` or used to fill a datatable, it returns no rows normally. If you only have one row, one column, then just use `command.ExecuteScalar()`. Don't `ToString` a number only to convert it back again, just cast it using `(int)`. And `AttachDbFilename` is a bad idea, instead attach your database normally. Don't hard-code the connection string, put it into a settings file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here

```
UPDATE Account SET AccBalance ='" + Convert.ToDouble(newBalance) + "'WHERE AccountNum =" + txtAccount.Text.Trim() + ""
```

In the runtime, for example, newBalance = 1 and then txtAccount.Text = "My name" the result will be

```
UPDATE Account SET AccBalance ='1'WHERE AccountNum =My Name
```

As you can see:

- No space between 1' and WHERE
- No ' before and after "My Name"

That's why the code can't work and now you know how to fix it.

As some comment already above, you should use SQLCommand Params instead of building raw SQL string https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: Well, that's *a* problem. I suspect (given the error message) that the actual exception is being thrown earlier, at `Convert.ToInt32(txtAmmount.Text)`, but we can't tell for sure...

Comment: Yes. You're right.  I didn't see it before. I thought it should be an error while querying the database. I always use EntityFramework to query the data so I'm not sure what does the error message should be when using raw SQL like above.